# Java Flux vs. Observable/BehaviorSubject

Tags: java, spring, rx-java, project-reactor, reactive-streams

My question is whether or not Flux has the ability to behave like an Observable or BehaviorSubject. I think I get the gist of what a Flux does and how, but every tutorial I see creates a Flux of static content, i.e. some pre-existing array of numbers which are finite in nature.

However, I want my Flux to be a stream of unknown values over time... like an Observable or BehaviorSubject. With those, you can create a method like setNextValue(String value), and pump those values to all subscribers of the Observable/BehaviorSubject etc.

Is this possible with a Flux? Or does the Flux have to be composed of an Observable type stream of values first?

**Update**

I answered my own question with an implementation down below. The accepted answer will lead down same path probably, but slightly complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved like this:

```
private EmitterProcessor<String> processor;
private FluxSink<String> statusSink;
private Flux<String> status;

public constructor() {
    this.processor = EmitterProcessor.create();
    this.statusSink = this.processor.sink(FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.BUFFER);
    this.status = this.processor.publish().autoConnect();
}

public Flux<String> getStatus() {
    return this.status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.statusSink.next(status);
}
```

Comment: I tested your solution but it unfortunately uses deprecated APIs.

Answer (score 1):

> every tutorial I see creates a Flux of static content, i.e. some pre-existing array of numbers which are finite in nature.

You'll see this because most tutorials focus on how to manipulate & use a `Flux` - but the implication here (that you can just use a `Flux` with static, fixed-length content) is both unfortunate, and wrong. It's much more powerful than that, and using it with such static content is almost certainly *not* how you see it used in the real-world.

There's essentially 3 different ways of instantiating a `Flux` to emit elements dynamically as you describe:

> However, I want my Flux to be a stream of unknown values over time... like an Observable or BehaviorSubject. With those, you can create a method like setNextValue(String value), and pump those values to all subscribers of the Observable/BehaviorSubject etc.

Absolutely - have a look at [`Flux.push()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#push-java.util.function.Consumer-). This exposes an emitter, and `emitter.next(value)` can be called whenever you wish. This stream can go on for as long as you want it to (infinitely, if desired.) [`Flux.create()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#create-java.util.function.Consumer-) is essentially the multi-threaded variant of `Flux.push()`, which may also be of use.

[`Flux.generate()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#generate-java.util.function.Consumer-) may also be worth a look - this is a bit like an "on-demand" version of `Flux.push()`, where you only emit the next element via a callback when the downstream consumer requests it, rather than emitting whenever you want to. This isn't always practical, but it makes sense to use this method if the use-case makes it feasible, as it respects backpressure and thus can be guaranteed not to overwhelm the consumer with more requests than it can handle.

Comment: Thanks, I had seen those recently, but trying to find a good example of how to use them. Essentially I am trying to create a StatusService which exposes a Flux<String> of the most recent status (which would be updated by a method accepting a String and emitting that value to the Flux which is subscribed to by whatever other components/classes).

So I will try to make that happen with those methods.